# On 10.04 Lucid, how can I add a script to startup to run as another user?

Tags: boot, command-line, reboot, init, init.d

On 10.04 Lucid, how can I add a script to run at startup as another user?

Will I add a script someplace like `/etc/init.d/myscript` ? Or is it better to put it in the cron file for root as `@reboot` and the `exec` command? Or something completely different?

I'm new to this (sorry) but I have been googling without much luck. Links to tutorials would be fine as well, I'm just feeling a little lost not knowing where to start...

Comment: Depending on what you want to run and when ... If you want it to run at boot, put it in `/etc/rc.local` By default it will run as root. To run it as another user, use sudo `sudo -u user_to_run_as <command>` If you want to run something when you log in, that is different , `gnome-session-properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password). It suggests something like this -

> Call `visudo` and add this:
>
> `user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /home/user2/bin/test.sh`
>
> The command paths
>   must be absolute! Then call
>   `sudo -u user2 /home/user2/bin/test.sh` from a user1 shell. Done.

That way you just put the script to run at startup under Startup Applications (System -> Preferences-> Startup Applications) and it'll run on startup